# How can I upload to Ubuntu Wallpaper Contest?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-background

Is there any other way to upload original content (wallpapers, pattern, etc.) to Ubuntu Design, without using the flickr contest...?

Usually the contest were for Ubuntu, but [the latest contest](http://www.flickr.com/groups/2484760@N20/) is called Ubuntu GNOME, will the wallpaper contest be available for Ubuntu?

Comment: For your second question, you may get the wallpapers if you install Gnome, but they may be installed anyway, as Unity is a derivative of Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the Trusty Tahr Wallpaper Submission Group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/2535978@N21).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: chaos: of course it does. He was looking for the ubuntu (not ubuntu gnome) wallpaper contest. And the link I provided, is the answer. I was looking for the same thing, and this is how I ended up here.